# I would like to extract x and y values from a txt file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have some code which stores x and y values into a txt file. The txt file stores the values on each line every time I tell the program to store the data.

It reads like this in the txt file:

`[(1.0, 1.80), (2.0, 1.80), (3.0, 0.70), etc...]`

I tried to extract the values using the `np.genfromtxt()` function, but I keep getting the values `nan`. I read through the documentation but I can't seem to interpret it.

How can I store these x and y values into varibles so that I can further work with them outside of the txt file?

Comment: Is each line beginning with `[` and ending with `]`?

Comment: Yes, an example would be [(1.0, 1.80), (2.0, 1.80), (3.0, 0.70)]

Comment: Do the several lines have a meaning except that you manually saved them or should all the x values of the whole file be put into one variable and all the y values in a second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast

with open(filename) as infile:         #Read file
    for line in infile:                #Iterate Each line
        print(ast.literal_eval(line))  #Convert to python object
```

**Output:**

```
[(1.0, 1.8), (2.0, 1.8), (3.0, 0.7)]
[(1.0, 1.8), (2.0, 1.8), (3.0, 0.7)]
[(1.0, 1.8), (2.0, 1.8), (3.0, 0.7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of all those brackets and white spaces is exactly like you posted:

```
x = []
y = []
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pairs = line[1:-2].split('),')
        for p in pairs:
            x.append(float(p.split(', ')[0].strip()[1:]))
            y.append(float(p.split(', ')[1].strip()))

# print(x, y)
# [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] [1.8, 1.8, 0.7]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but  the code above works for me.

Comment: Fine for me, your welcome. However, I'd be interested in the answer of my question above: Do you need simply two arrays for x- and y-data or a list of a list of x-y-tuples?

Comment: I just need two arrays for the x and y data. I am just graphing it with matplotlib which is working.

Comment: But - if I may state this here - that's exactly what my script provides as a result (in contrast to the `ast.literal_eval` solution). You can immediately do `plt.plot(x, y)`.